# How to make steps bar in android like Bootstrap

Tags: java, android, android-layout, progress-bar

Hello Is there anyway or library that can help me create like this image of bootstrap steps progress bar in android with text and icon ???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **stepView**

```
<com.baoyachi.stepview.HorizontalStepView
            android:id="@+id/step_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
```

> Reference : 1.https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView, 2.https://github.com/shuhart/StepView 3.https://github.com/shadowsong91/StepView

Comment: I have overwrite another font for my app the first element of the step doesn't take the new font , how can i do that ?